# How do I turn part of a plain text into an URL clickable link?

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering if its possible to turn plain text like this:

```
<text>Hello everyone, check out my website www.clickablelink.com!</text>
```

and turn it into something like this:

```
<text>Hello everyone, check out my website <a href="http://www.clickablelink.com">www.clickablelink.com!</a></text>
```

I am working on a webbapplication where the users should be able to post messages, and If anyone chooses to write something like: "Hey, check out my website - www~", then that link should be clickable.

I use visual studio (MVC/JS/jQuery).

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but... looks like this is some type of text-matching / replacement task. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? As written, this question is very broad: lots of ways to accomplish this. So this looks like more of a "write code for me" question.

Comment: Hi David Makogon, I've tried for a long time using javascript/jquery and I didnt get anywhere - None of it worked, thats why Im asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, this is possible, with the following steps:

1. Craft a regex to find where the website string starts and ends, so that you only modify the website part of the string. This will be different depending on your **exact** URL specifications, but `/(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-z]{3}\.?([a-z]+)?/` should suffice.
2. Target the `<text>` tag that you want to modify, preferably with **[`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)**, saving its **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** to a variable.
3. Run a **[`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** against the element using the regex as a parameter, and save this variable for use later on.
4. Use **[`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** to replace the string with the same string wrapped in a formatted `<a>` tag. Note that because you omit the protocol in your example, you'll need to **add one in** while replacing, or else it will be treated as a **folder** of the **current** website you are on.
5. Set the `.innerHTML` of the element to the replacement.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var regex = /(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-z]{3}\.?([a-z]+)?/;
var str = document.getElementsByTagName('text')[0].innerHTML;
var matches = str.match(regex);
var replacement = str.replace(regex, "<a href='http://" + matches[0] + "'>" + matches[0] + "</a>");
document.getElementsByTagName('text')[0].innerHTML = replacement;
```

```html
<text>Hello everyone, check out my website www.clickablelink.com!</text>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Can you elaborate why you chose to use the `.match()` method opposed to using `$1` in the new Substring?

Comment: @RMo -- Because I'd temporarily forgotten that you could do that :) Yes, that would be a more concise solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way how you can use regular expressions to achieve this. Do keep in mind that this example will need some polishing to match the appropriate strings. This will for example only match links starting with www and ending with .com.

```js
// retreive the text
let textElement = document.getElementById('text');
let text = textElement.innerHTML;

// find and replace text that looks like a link using a
// regularExpression. This example will only replace links
// that start with 'www' and end with '.com'. If you need
// to match other strings change the regular expression 
// accordingly.
let processedText = text.replace(/(\bw{3}.*\.com\b)/g, '<a href="http:\\\\$1">$1</a>');

// output the new text
textElement.innerHTML = processedText;
```

```html
<text id="text">Hello everyone, check out my website www.clickablelink.com!</text>
```

Comment: MDN documentation on the `.replace` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace